# Reducing type text font when \texttt is inside a \newcommand

Tags: macros, fontsize, typewriter

I am trying to reduce the font size of `\texttt{}` only, but the problem is that when I do it, the whole text (except for the tt!!) is reduced.

My current packages are the below:

```
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance, xurl}
```

And I am trying to redefine a command, so that I can use this in a straightforward manner:

```
\newcommand{\commentEx}[1]{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}
```

**Note:** I was using `fancyvrb` before, but it didn't wrap the text and caused overflow hboxes. Therefore, *I do not want to use it*.

Comment: you have not shown how any code related to font size, which is presumably the code with your error. I would guess you had used the incorrect syntax `\small{text here}`  (which will make the rest of the document small), instead of `{\small text here}` (which will just make `text here` small).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

EDITED to use `\NewCommandCopy`, rather than `\let` for copy making.

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewCommandCopy{\svtt}{\texttt}
\renewcommand\texttt[1]{\svtt{\footnotesize#1}}
\begin{document}
This is \texttt{a test of tt size} back to normal?
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only wanted it to affect `\commentEx` and not all occurrences of `\texttt`, you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance, xurl}
\newcommand{\commentEx}[1]{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{\textbf{\texttt{%
  \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont#1}}}}
\begin{document}
This is \texttt{a test of tt size} back to normal?

This is \commentEx{a test of tt size} back to normal?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, I chose `palatino`, only because the `tt` font is available in bold.